# NSDictionary to NSArray and back to NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm trying to show comments from disqus.com in my UITableView.

Now I have:
1.

```
//Creating NSArray with comments only from NSDictionary Dict
    comments = [dict objectForKey:@"response"];
            NSLog(@"MessageArray:%@ count:%i", comments, [comments count]);
            [tableViewNew reloadData];
```

2.

```
//I'm trying to get NSDictionary from NSArray, but it isn't work
NSDictionary *currentComment = [comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//currentComment = nil
```

In my *.h file I have this:

```
NSArray* comments;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray* comments;
```

And my comments array text:

```
(
        {
        author =         {
            about = "";
            avatar =             {
                cache = "http://mediacdn.disqus.com/1321567697/images/noavatar92.png";
                permalink = "http://disqus.com/api/users/avatars/itruf.jpg";
            };
            emailHash = 7741f7b9bbf2a05ff782550412b9a513;
            id = 16898031;
            isAnonymous = 0;
            joinedAt = "2011-09-17T17:17:16";
            name = itruf;
            profileUrl = "http://disqus.com/itruf/";
            url = "";
            username = itruf;
        };
        createdAt = "2011-11-19T06:28:28";
        dislikes = 0;
        forum = smartfiction;
        id = 368112946;
        isApproved = 1;
        isDeleted = 0;
        isEdited = 0;
        isFlagged = 0;
        isHighlighted = 0;
        isJuliaFlagged = 1;
        isSpam = 0;
        likes = 0;
        media =         (
        );
        message = "\U0422\U0435\U0441\U0442. \U041f\U0440\U043e\U0448\U0443 \U043d\U0435 \U0433\U043d\U0435\U0432\U0430\U0442\U044c\U0441\U044f.<br><br><br><br>!!!!!!<br><br>\U0410\U0430 \U0411\U0431 \U0412\U0432 \U0413\U0433 \U0414\U0434 \U0415\U0435 \U0401\U0451 \U0416\U0436 \U0417\U0437 \U0418\U0438 \U0419\U0439 \U041a\U043a \U041b\U043b \U041c\U043c \U041d\U043d \U041e\U043e \U041f\U043f \U0420\U0440 \U0421\U0441 \U0422\U0442 \U0423\U0443 \U0424\U0444 \U0425\U0445 \U0426\U0446 \U0427\U0447 \U0428\U0448 \U0429\U0449 \U042a\U044a \U042b\U044b \U042c\U044c \U042d\U044d \U042e\U044e \U042f\U044f";
        parent = "<null>";
        points = 0;
        "raw_message" = "\U0422\U0435\U0441\U0442. \U041f\U0440\U043e\U0448\U0443 \U043d\U0435 \U0433\U043d\U0435\U0432\U0430\U0442\U044c\U0441\U044f.\n\n\n\n!!!!!!\n\n\U0410\U0430 \U0411\U0431 \U0412\U0432 \U0413\U0433 \U0414\U0434 \U0415\U0435 \U0401\U0451 \U0416\U0436 \U0417\U0437 \U0418\U0438 \U0419\U0439 \U041a\U043a \U041b\U043b \U041c\U043c \U041d\U043d \U041e\U043e \U041f\U043f \U0420\U0440 \U0421\U0441 \U0422\U0442 \U0423\U0443 \U0424\U0444 \U0425\U0445 \U0426\U0446 \U0427\U0447 \U0428\U0448 \U0429\U0449 \U042a\U044a \U042b\U044b \U042c\U044c \U042d\U044d \U042e\U044e \U042f\U044f";
        thread = 475714714;
    },
        {
        author =         {
            avatar =             {
                cache = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=2c5d4ef0caae2eb294f9f85cff0fa88b&size=32&default=http://mediacdn.disqus.com/1321567697/images/noavatar32.png";
                permalink = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar.php?gravatar_id=2c5d4ef0caae2eb294f9f85cff0fa88b&size=32&default=http://mediacdn.disqus.com/1321567697/images/noavatar32.png";
            };
            emailHash = 2c5d4ef0caae2eb294f9f85cff0fa88b;
            isAnonymous = 1;
            name = "\U0421\U0435\U0440\U0433\U0435\U0439";
            profileUrl = "http://disqus.com/guest/2c5d4ef0caae2eb294f9f85cff0fa88b/";
            url = "";
        };
        createdAt = "2011-11-18T07:36:47";
        dislikes = 0;
        forum = smartfiction;
        id = 367328215;
        isApproved = 1;
        isDeleted = 0;
        isEdited = 0;
        isFlagged = 0;
        isHighlighted = 0;
        isJuliaFlagged = 1;
        isSpam = 0;
        likes = 1;
        media =         (
        );
        message = "\U041a\U043b\U0430\U0441\U0441!!! \U0420\U0430\U0431\U043e\U0447\U0438\U0439 \U043a\U043e\U043c\U0430\U043d\U0434\U0443\U0435\U0442 \U043c\U0435\U043d\U0435\U0434\U0436\U0435\U0440\U043e\U043c! \U0414\U0430 \U043a\U0430\U043a \U0433\U0440\U0430\U043c\U043e\U0442\U043d\U043e \U043e\U043d \U044d\U0442\U043e \U0434\U0435\U043b\U0430\U0435\U0442! \U0410 \U043c\U0438\U0441\U0442\U0435\U0440 \U0413\U0440\U0438\U043c\U043c\U0435\U0442, \U043f\U043e\U0445\U043e\U0436\U0435, \U0438 \U0432\U043f\U0440\U0430\U0432\U0434\U0443 \U0431\U043e\U043b\U0432\U0430\U043d.";
        parent = "<null>";
        points = 1;
        "raw_message" = "\U041a\U043b\U0430\U0441\U0441!!! \U0420\U0430\U0431\U043e\U0447\U0438\U0439 \U043a\U043e\U043c\U0430\U043d\U0434\U0443\U0435\U0442 \U043c\U0435\U043d\U0435\U0434\U0436\U0435\U0440\U043e\U043c! \U0414\U0430 \U043a\U0430\U043a \U0433\U0440\U0430\U043c\U043e\U0442\U043d\U043e \U043e\U043d \U044d\U0442\U043e \U0434\U0435\U043b\U0430\U0435\U0442! \U0410 \U043c\U0438\U0441\U0442\U0435\U0440 \U0413\U0440\U0438\U043c\U043c\U0435\U0442, \U043f\U043e\U0445\U043e\U0436\U0435, \U0438 \U0432\U043f\U0440\U0430\U0432\U0434\U0443 \U0431\U043e\U043b\U0432\U0430\U043d.";
        thread = 475714714;
    }
)
```

I want to have NSDictionary with all keys, from my array.
Thank you very much.

Comment: can you post the structure of json? without that its basically one blind man leading another...

Comment: I'm using this api method: http://disqus.com/api/docs/forums/listPosts/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
    NSDictionary *currentComment = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: [comments objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

I think you are using this in your "cellForRowAtIndex" method...So if yes..then before returning YES to the cell at last of this method release the dictionary. Otherwise sometine it may give you error or wrong data..Happy Coding:)